# How to avoid a huge .xcmappingmodel file for small datamodel changes?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration, xcdatamodel, mapping-model

I currently have a unique *MyProject.xcdatamodeld* file. It is fairly easy to do the following, as no additional step is required:

- add fields/classes

But I will need a *MyProject.xcmappingmodel* if I want to:

- remove a field/class
- rename a field/class
- change type of a field

My issue is that the initial size of the *.xcmappingmodel* (from model v1 to itself) is ranging from 2 MB to 10 MB and makes my app suddenly twice bigger!

If I want to make just a tiny change (removing or renaming a field), is there a way to do it without this huge size addition?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe can be done with a Core Data Lightweight Migration. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) states that you do not need a mapping model when the changes consist of

> - Simple addition of a new attribute
> - Removal of an attribute
> - A non-optional attribute becoming optional
> - An optional attribute becoming non-optional, and defining a default value
> - Renaming an entity or property